# Download a specific revision of a file in google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api

I can download  specific file by its iD,

1. get the downloadUrl
2. Download the content using get.

But I am not able to find anything which indicates, that I can download the specific revision of a file. Any pointer will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If you user the [Revisions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/list) part of the Drive API, you get get a list of revisions for a given document. Each revision comes with either an "ExportLinks" list, containing links with different export formats, or a downloadUrl (for non-Google files).

Using these, you can download a specific revision.

Comment: Thanks Thibault ! Let me check with the downloadUrl stuff. Thanks let me check with it . Thanks again.

Comment: Some time its been i just tried long back, but was a bit distracted from this topic. So trying again to figure out. What I am searching is a way in which I can download a version assuming I have the version Id only on my page. So on click I need to download the specific version of the file. Is it possible if I query the metadata and then download using downloadUrl something like the file download ...