# Get Google drive Api 3 Revision download url

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am trying to get the download url for a specific revision of a google drive file, but can't find how to do it.

Has anyone know a way to do it?

I am using the JAVA Google drive API 3.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download a specific revision of a file in google drive api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930406/download-a-specific-revision-of-a-file-in-google-drive-api)

Comment: I think this solution is old and it refers to the Google Drive API 2.0 version. For some reason the downloadUrl option is no longer available on the revision Object returned by the Google Drive API 3.0 and I wonder if there is another way of getting the link

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Basically the Google drive API 3.0 does not give you the downloadUrl any longer. Instead it gives you the possibility to just download the revision with the following code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
driveService.revisions().get(fileId, revisionId).executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);

byte[] content = outputStream.toByteArray();
try (FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(filePath)) {
    fout.write(content);
    fout.close();
}
```

Comment: getWebContentLink() contains the download url